# Good practice with css class and id

Tags: css, coding-style, code-cleanup

I'm wondering about clean code practices with css. Assuming I've got something like that:

```
#island1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: 55vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #222222;
  box-shadow: -17px -17px 34px #171717,
    17px 17px 34px #2d2d2d;
}
```

I would like to have 6 of those but with different sizes and margines. What is the best way to make it without reapeting the same code for each element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a class with properties that does not change

```css
.islands {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #222222;
  box-shadow: -17px -17px 34px #171717,
    17px 17px 34px #2d2d2d;
}
```

and for all the island, specify an other class or id with the sizes and margins

```css
#island1{
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: 55vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
}

#island2{
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes:

```
.island {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: 55vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #222222;
  box-shadow: -17px -17px 34px #171717,
    17px 17px 34px #2d2d2d;
}

.island1 {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: 15vh; 
}

.island2 {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 25vh; 
}

...

.island6 {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vw;
  margin-top: 35vh;
  margin-left: 45vh; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="island1" class="island island1"></div>
<div id="island2" class="island island2"></div>
...
<div id="island6" class="island island6"></div>
```